# Is there a way to fake emitting the signal?

Tags: qt

I don't use moc in the project. With new signal/slot syntax it works pretty good. But became necessary to emit signal in the derived Qt class.

It is possible without using moc?

Comment: you can create your own signal/slot-like architecture without moc (obviously something simpler, you don't have a moc pass..) and use it however you want. I did it some time ago and it worked pretty well

Comment: Relevant: http://woboq.com/blog/reflection-in-cpp-and-qt-moc.html

Comment: What are your reasons not to use moc?

Comment: @David Kernin, Thanks for the link, there is very informative article.

Answer (score 2):

**No, this is not possible.**

moc actually implements the signal function. If you look into the generated signal function by looking at the generated moc_myclass.cpp, you'll see that the signal function is nothing more than a call to `QMetaObject::activate`, and that function requires a pointer to the `QMetaObject` of the signal sender. Since without running moc, no metaobject is generated, you can't even call `QMetaObject::activate` manually.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a very nice blogentry about the moc currently:

http://woboq.com/blog/reflection-in-cpp-and-qt-moc.html

Comment: sry, just took a look @ planet as i remembered it being there